# Why not do Peterson's algorithm with a queue?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, locking, mutex

[Peterson's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm) is an algorithm for ensuring processes sharing memory don't access that memory at the same time. I've reproduced it below for a thread indexed i.

```
do {
    flag[i] = true
    turn = j
    while(flag[j] == true && turn == j){};

    #enter critical section

    flag[i] = false

    #remainder

} while (true);
```

Why would the following algorithm (using a shared queue 'queue') not provide process synchronization like Peterson's?

```
do {
    #push i into process queue
    queue.push i
    #busy wait until i is first
    while(queue.first != i){};

    #enter critical section

    #remove i from the queue and let the next process begin
    queue.pop

    #remainder

} while (true);
```

Comment: Note: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15675676/758133

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would, provided you can implement queue.push and queue.pop using some atomic mechanism.   In general, queue.push must update multiple locations  atomically.  To do this, you need some form of serialization, like Petersons algorithm.

The point in Petersons algorithm is to provide this service without any fancy hardware or software support -- just a simple coherent memory device is sufficient.